# Equality of matrix commutation within the trace operation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, trace, kronecker-product

I am working on one specific problem, which mounts to prove the following equation. Say $a\in\mathbb{R}^n,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In what situation does the following equality hold?

$$
tr(ba^\intercal A)=tr(a^\intercal b A)
$$

Much appreciated!

PS: More about the setting (linear mixed effect model)
$$
Y=\boldsymbol{X}_1\beta + \boldsymbol{X}_2u + \boldsymbol{e},u\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_u^2I_q),\boldsymbol{e}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_e^2I_n),
$$
and based on Mixed Model Equations (MME), we have
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}&=(\boldsymbol{x}_{1}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}_{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}_{1}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y},\\
\boldsymbol{\widehat{u}}&=(\boldsymbol{x}_{2}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{x}_{2}+\lambda I_q)^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}_{2}^{\intercal}(\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{x}_{1}\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})
\end{aligned}
with $\boldsymbol{V}=\sigma_e^2 I_n+\sigma_u^2\boldsymbol{X}_2\boldsymbol{X}_2^\intercal,\lambda=\sigma_e^2/\sigma_u^2$. And I am intended to prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}^\intercal Y\mid\boldsymbol{X},u)=
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}^\intercal \widehat{Y}\mid\boldsymbol{X},u)
$$
with $\widehat{Y}=\boldsymbol{X}_1\widehat{\beta} + \boldsymbol{X}_2\widehat{u}$ where $\boldsymbol{X}_2$ is the random intercept (e.g. the first row can be $(1,0,\cdots,0)$ etc.), which mounts to my question at beginning. Any other methods all also appreciated!

Comment: Can you give more context about your "specific problem"? The equality does not hold in general.

Comment: @angryavian For sure; Please refer to my edited question for more details. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $tr ((ba^t-b^ta Id)A)=0$. This says that $A$ is orthogonal to $(ab^t-b^taId)$ in the ($n^2$ dimensional) space of matrices. As soon as $n>1$ and $a \neq 0, b\neq 0$ the matrix $(ab^t-b^taId)$ is non-zero (proof: if $b^ta\neq 0$ it has rank $\geq n-1$ and if $b^ta=0$ it has rank 1 unless $a=0$ or $b=0$), so there will be a $n^2-1$ dimensional subspace of matrices $A$ for which this is true.

Comment: Thanks! You are saying that it is equal to show that $A$ is actually in the null space of $(ba^\intercal−b^\intercal a I_d)$ ?

Comment: @CYgao I don't think so. $A$ is a matrix. On the $n^2$ dimensional space of matrices the "standard" dot product  is equal to $\langle B, A \rangle=tr(B^tA)$. I'm saying $A$ is orthogonal to $ab^t-b^ta I_n$ in this dot product.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for the answer, I'll follow your lead and try to dig more info up. :)

Comment: Note that one can construct a matrix $(A)$ which is orthogonal to a given matrix $(B=ab^T-b^TaI\ne 0)$ using an arbitrary matrix $(X)$ as follows
$$A = X - \left(\frac{B:X}{B:B}\right) B\quad\implies\quad B:A=0$$
where the colon is used as a product notation for the trace, i.e. $\;B:X={\rm Tr}(BX^T)$